# Installing msgpack as Apache module on Debian 11

Tags: php, apache, msgpack

I need to use msgpack within a mixture of CLI and web scripts so I installed the PHP msgpack module using:

```
apt install php8.2-msgpack
```

and my CLI scripts can successfully call the msgpack_pack() and msgpack_unpack() functions.

However, when I run another script within Apache it fails and checking with function_exists() shows that it's not installed msgpack as an Apache module.  I've restarted Apache but it's made no difference.

If it helps, the msgpack.so library is contained in the /usr/lib/php/20220829/ directory but not in /usr/lib/php/20210902/.

What have I missed out ?